# Intersection of thickly syndetic sets

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, ergodic-theory

**Question**: Let $\Gamma$ be a countable group. Is the intersection of two thickly syndetic sets still thickly syndetic?

I've only seen the proof for the group $\mathbb{Z}$ (and I believe this method generalises to amenable groups).
(there is an "extra" question below)

*Background*:

- a set $S \subset \Gamma$ is **syndetic** if there is a finite $A \subset \Gamma$ to that $AS = \Gamma$.
- $T$ is **thick** if for all finite $F \subset \Gamma$, $\cap_{f \in F} fT \neq \emptyset$.
- $U$ is **thickly syndetic**, if for any finite $F \subset \Gamma$, $U' = \cap_{f \in F} fL$ is syndetic.

*Partial answer*: It's an exercise to see that if $S$ is syndetic and $T$ is thick, then their intersection is non-empty. Indeed, if $A$ is the set for which $S$ is syndetic, then
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \bigcap_{a' \in A} a'T 
&= \displaystyle \Gamma \cap \big( \bigcap_{a' \in A} a'T \big) \\
&= \displaystyle \big( \cup_{a \in A}  aS \big) \cap \big( \bigcap_{a' \in A} a'T \big)\\
&= \displaystyle \bigcup_{a \in A} \bigg( aS  \cap \big( \bigcap_{a' \in A} a'T \big) \bigg)\\
&= \displaystyle \bigcup_{a \in A} a \bigg( S  \cap \big( \bigcap_{a' \in A} a^{-1}a'T \big) \bigg)\\
& \subseteq \displaystyle  \bigcup_{a \in A} a \big( S  \cap T \big) 
\end{array}
$$
Since $T$ is thick the $S \cap T$ is non-empty.
Now if $T$ is thickly syndetic, then $S \cap T$ is even syndetic. 
However this argument does not yield thickly syndetic.

**extra question**: it's another exercise to show that a set $S$ is syndetic iff its intersection with any thick is non-empty. Likewise a set is syndetic iff its intersection with any thick is non-empty. 
Is a set thickly syndetic iff its intersection with any thickly syndetic set is thickly syndetic?

Comment: If the first question is true then the extra question is also true since any set contains a thickly syndetic set is also thickly syndetic.I remember a fact I learned in a course on topological dynamics that a set is thickly syndetic iff its intersection with any picewise syndetic set (the intersection of a syndetic set and a thick set) is non-empty. Maybe this result is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just realised the answer is obvious... one needs only to replace $S$ by $S' = \displaystyle \cap_{f \in F} S$ and $T$ by $T' = \displaystyle \cap_{f \in F} T$. Now if $S$ and $T$ are thickly syndetic, then $S'$ is syndetic and $T'$ is thick (so the same argument follows). Since $S'  \cap T' = \displaystyle \bigcap_{f \in F} (S \cap T)$, one gets the conclusion...

Comment: I am sorry that I did not quite understand your argument. It seems that you have proved that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{f \in F} f(S \cap T)$ is a piecewise syndetic set and it seems this can not imply the intersection is thickly syndetic as piecewise syndetic is weaker than syndetic.

Comment: Perhaps because I did not put emphasis on the following fact: If $T$ is thickly syndetic then, for any finite set $F$, $\displaystyle \bigcap_{f \in F} fT$ is still thickly syndetic. Indeed, if $E$ is another finite set, then $\displaystyle \bigcap_{e \in E} e \big( \bigcap_{f \in F} fT \big) = \bigcap_{e \in E} \big( \bigcap_{f \in F} ef T \big) = \bigcap_{d \in EF} d T$. Since $EF$ is still finite, the fact follows.

Comment: So basically the argument I wrote was to show that the intersection of a thick set $T$ and a syndetic set $S$  is non-empty. Because of the fact, if $T$ is thickly syndetic this argument shows that the intersection is actually syndetic. Now if $S$ is also thickly syndetic, the argument in my first comment uses the fact that for any $F$, $S'$ and $T'$ are still thickly syndetic. In particular, $S'$ is syndetic and $T'$ is thickly syndetic. So their intersection $\displaystyle \bigcap_{f \in F} f(S \cap T)$ is syndetic. Since this holds for any $F$, this means that $S \cap T$ is thickly syndetic

Comment: Is there any chance, that someone could send me link to to proof of this theorem for Z. Thanks